# SPSecurityEventReceiver in office 365 or SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint, office365

Can we use SPSecurityEventReceiver  in sharepoint online or office 365?

We need to identify the persons who are given full control over sites/lists and send email to them to attend some sort training/enrollement.

We can do this in on-primises setup. However, can the same be done in Sahrepoint online/office 365?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible to use **SPSecurityEventReceiver** , But if you need an event receiver you can try **remote event receiver** for app

http://blog.kloud.com.au/2014/03/13/remote-event-receiver-rer-for-host-web-using-sharepoint-provider-hosted-app-in-office-365sharepoint-online-environment/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220043.aspx